# How to fix CVE-2021-43267 in centos 7

Tags: centos, rhel, kernel

**The latest official release of Linux kernel released by Centos is kernel-3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64.rpm which is updated on 15th October 2021.**

[image]

Furthermore, the kernel version recommended by `CVE-2021-4326` is provided by a third party repository named **ElRepo** which means that the recommended kernel update is not yet supported/released officially by Centos repositories? Or how secure is to update the kernel from any other source then centos official repo.

Although did try to update the kernel of one of our dev environment server to the latest recommended kernel version i.e 5.15.2. This resulted in a broken operating system where after reboot, the system landed in Kernel emergency mode as it was unable to boot from the updated kernel and couldn’t configure the boot partitions automatically.

Currently, our production servers are running on `Linux Kernel 3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64` which can be updated to the latest **stable** `release 3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64`.

Under all these observations, Should we to stick with official Centos updates only as updating the kernel from third party sources may break operating system functionality in production environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CentOS 7 and RHEL 7 kernels [aren’t affected by CVE-2021-43267](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-43267), so there’s no need to do anything.

Comment: To illustrate this: `/boot/config-3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64:# CONFIG_TIPC is not set` (same for whatever version)

Answer (score -3):

Cent OS & RHEL have addressed this in their most recent firmware and security updates.

If you run :

```
yum install kernel kernel-tools kernel-tools-libs
```

That will add the new firmware & kernel patches.